# How can I use \apptocmd within a macro, passing the appended's macro's parameter back to itself?

Tags: macros, expansion, etoolbox

Let's say I have the following

```
\newcommand\app[1]{\textbf{#1}} % <- #1 is appended's macro's parameter
\apptocmd{\app}{#1}{}{} % <- passing appended macro's parameter to appended macro again

\app{Food App}
```

Macro `\app` will look like -> `\textbf{#1}#1`

Let's say I want to write every occurrence of `\app` to a file:

```
\newwrite\appfile
\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\appfile=\jobname-app.txt}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\appfile} 
\apptocmd{\app}{\immediate\write\appfile{#1}}{}{}
```

## Problem

Now let's say I want to be schnazzy and write every occurrence of app to a file, but only when "debug" mode is on.

So I could

1. surround this in a macro
2. surround this in an conditional

For option number 1, I do not know what to do with my parameter `#1`. I tried using `\noexpand#1`, but it does not work. I need to pass the `#1` to the original `\app` macro.

```
\newcommand\debugmode{
  \newwrite\appfile
  \AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\appfile=\jobname-app.txt}
  \AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\appfile} 
  \apptocmd{\app}{\immediate\write\appfile{#1}}{}{}
}
\debugmode
```

Option 2, is applied real-time while parsing, which is not ideal for my situation (my situation is not shown here):

```
  \newif\ifdebugmode
  \ifdebugmode %
  \newwrite\appfile
  \AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\appfile=\jobname-app.txt}
  \AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\appfile} 
  \apptocmd{\app}{\immediate\write\appfile{#1}}{}{}
  \fi

  \debugmodetrue
```

## Example

See remarks in code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\app[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand\debugmode{
  \newwrite\appfile
  \AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\appfile=\jobname-app.txt}
  \AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\appfile} 
  \apptocmd{\app}{\immediate\write\appfile{#1}}{}{} % <-- #1 not expanded correctly, because it is embedded. LaTeX expects ##1
}
\debugmode

\begin{document}
\app{Food App}
\app{Dictionary App}
\end{document}
```

And by the way, to my disappointment, I actually had to revert to LaTeX2e because LaTeX3 does not really support patching. :( I find myself going back to the roots...TeX

Comment: You need `##1` in place of `#1` for option (1).

Comment: @cfr Tried that. Doesnt work. I should have mentioned that. This is because ##1 gets passed to the original (appended macro). You end up with `\textbf{#1}##1`. I think this is the case.

Comment: Actually, the patch to `\app` fails. The definition remains just `\textbf{#1}`. Two ways to see this: use the empty arguments of `\apptocmd`; add `\show\app` at the end of the `\debugmode` definition.

Comment: The no-patching in l3 is status-by-design if you are referring to macros defined with `\DeclareDocumentCommand` and friends. As I understand it, if you want to patch, you're doing it wrong. (I haven't wanted to patch, but I'm also doing it wrong, as I understand it ;).)

Comment: Is `fontspec` reqlly required to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: @cfr It is there only to indicate the compiler is xelatex.

Comment: But the issue doesn't depend on the engine. You can reproduce equally with pdfLaTeX etc. In any case, it doesn't indicate XeLaTeX. It indicates either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr you never know. always easier to say in hindsight. I always load fontspec to indicate my compiler, because that is essential information for others to reproduce the original conditions. I don't expect it in the answer, of course. It does matter that you can reproduce conditions in an environment different than the original to a scientist ;) again, easier to say in hindsight, so I include it. There is an occassion I remember with pgf patterns where this made a huge difference.

Comment: If you think the engine might matter, you need to specify it in the question: XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are not equivalent and both can use `fontspec`. So saying what you compile with would be more helpful in that case.

Comment: Good point. Added remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\apptocmd` doesn't like to be in the argument to another command when `#` is involved.

You can do it with a conditional:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\app[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newif\ifdebugmode
\debugmodetrue % comment for not applying the patches
\ifdebugmode
  \newwrite\appfile
  \AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\appfile=\jobname-app.txt} 
  \AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\appfile} 
  \apptocmd\app{\immediate\write\appfile{\unexpanded{\app{#1}}}}{}{} 
\fi

\begin{document}

\app{Food App}
\app{Dictionary App}

\end{document}
```

(I left off `fontspec` that's not relevant to the application).

The contents of the `-app.txt` file will be

```
\app {Food App}
\app {Dictionary App}
```

Alternatively, use `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newcommand\app[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand\debugmode{%
  \newwrite\appfile
  \AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\appfile=\jobname-app.txt}
  \AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\appfile}
  \xapptocmd\app{\immediate\write\appfile{\unexpanded{\app{##1}}}}{}{}
}
\debugmode

\begin{document}

\app{Food App}
\app{Dictionary App}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am unclear on the detailed behavior desired, but...

Is this what is desired?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\app[1]{\textbf{#1}} % <- #1 is appended's macro's parameter
\def\addtoapp#1{%
  \apptocmd{\app}{#1}{}{} % <- passing appended macro's parameter to appended macro again
}
\begin{document}
\app{Food App}
\addtoapp{This is a test}

\app{Food App}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\app[1]{\def\tmp{#1}\textbf{\tmp}} % <- #1 is appended's macro's parameter
\def\addtoapp#1{%
  \xpatchcmd{\app}{{\tmp}}{{#1}}{}{} % <- passing appended macro's parameter to appended macro again
}
\begin{document}
\app{Food App}
\addtoapp{This is a test}

\app{Food App}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @macmadness86 I am not sure of the issue.  I can add `xparse` to my MWE, either before or after `xpatch` and get no option clash.  Perhaps you can edit your MWE to reflect it.

Comment: @macmadness86 Carry on bravely.  We will await an eventual edit.

Comment: I used `\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}`, but `\RequirePackage{xpatch}` in my package loads it without that parameter I suppose. There is some `\PassOptionToPackage` trick maybe for this.

Comment: @macmadness86 I only have the problem cited if I load `xparse` after `xpatch`.  Try loading those two packages in the reverse order.

Comment: @macmadness86 Just for some perspective, there is nothing TeXwise blasphemous about requiring a certain package load order.  It is well known, for example, that `hyperref` should always be loaded as late as possible.

Comment: Oh! Is *this* what's required? (+1) for understanding the question ;).

Comment: Yes I know about hyperref and bookmark, but I do see it is a usability problem with latex. It is hard enough getting the dang document to compile, and then on top of that you have to deal with package order!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry to steal your answered check mark away, but after closer investigation, I realized that egreg answered the question with his `regexpatch` option. The conditional, which I already described in my question, has the limitation that the `\debugmodetrue` switch cannot come after the conditional. The `regexpatch` option allows me to use `##1`, yet refer to the appended macro's `#1`, not the `#1` of `\debugmode` scope. This was not the case with your answer. Maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: @macmadness86  No problem.  egreg is the best and his answers are typically definitive in their scope.  Best wishes.